# I have installed Linux on my Windows 8.1 laptop. Can I upgrade to Windows 10?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, windows-10-upgrade

My laptop is running on Windows 8.1 and a year before I installed Ubuntu Linux. If I try to upgrade to Windows 10, there will be a problem or not, because of Liniux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no problem. 
I suppose you are dual booting Windows and Ubuntu. If that is the case, then Just upgrade the Windows 8.1 with Windows Update to Windows 10.